# Is there a name for the style of the 'superhero' Russian statues?

Tags: russia, monument

Is there a name for the style of the 'superhero' Russian statues?
I can only find one example which is a statue of [Yuri Gagarin](http://www.moscow-russia-insiders-guide.com/images/moscow-monuments-yuri-gagarin-statue.jpg)  But I have seen similar statues in documentaries and movies.

Comment: [Socialist Realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_realism)?  Or you could search for one of the [sites that discusses the style](https://espionart.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/gagarin-the-soviet-superman/).

Comment: [Is it a bird? Is it a plane? No, it's Superman and friends... painted on Soviet war statue by the Banksy of Bulgaria](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2004814/Is-bird-Is-plane-No-Superman-friends-painted-Soviet-statue-Banksy-Bulgaria.html#ixzz44fRd0OGL)

Answer (score 3):

There was no special name for hero statues style, at least in the Soviet Union.
"Socialist realism", according to Soviet official definition, was not a particular style but a general method (as they called it, but a more adequate translation would be "philosophy") in art. It applied to all art, not specially to hero statues. Here are some of the most famous examples:

- [The Motherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Motherland_Calls)
- [The Motherland calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Motherland_Calls)
- [Rabochiy & Kolhoznica](http://artpoisk.info/artist/muhina_vera_ignat_evna_1889/rabochiy_i_kolhoznica/)

There is a lot of similarity with [Nazi art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_of_the_Third_Reich) as seen [here](http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7kLYLWpAERg/UP9CgD7M3KI/AAAAAAACDCk/NVS1MYrplzs/s900/aa2.jpg), for example.

[This style outlived Soviet Union by the way](https://www.flickr.com/photos/e_chaya/7926370932)

Comment: That really has nothing to do with National Socialist art, besides anti-degeneracy. Socialist Realism was supposed to be mundane and National Socialist art was supposed to be idealized. The Motherland Calls is totally opposite National Socialist art and the Fatherland. As far as I can tell you're just making stuff up randomly based on vague similarity. I mean, the works progress administration used Fascist symbology extensively but does that mean public infrastructure is fascist?

Comment: And on my opinion there is a lot of similarity. Guess whose art is this: http://www.usmbooks.com/images/HausDEKunstCat/1942/GKA42-4.jpg

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are talking about [Socialist realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_realism) or possibly [Brutalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brutalist_architecture)(to be fair, Brutalism was made in the UK, but it was still popular in the USSR).

Comment: It would be useful if you could add some details / explanations to your answer.

Comment: Brutalism is more of an architectural style, and less of fine art.